# Facing the problem of Initializing the tree i.e. root of the tree

Tags: c, tree, binary-search-tree

**Binary search tree operations.**

Facing problem while first insertion of node.

Changes in the root of function are not reflecting in the main function.

Tried initiazing the root in the main function, it worked, like insert function is working fine in that case. But when the tree is empty and first time we have to add an element then it is not getting added into the tree.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *left, *right;
}node;

void insert(node *root, int x)
{
    node *newrec, *p, *q;
    newrec = (node *) malloc(sizeof(node));
    newrec->data = x;
    newrec->left = NULL;
    newrec->right = NULL;

    if(root == NULL)
    {
        root = newrec;
        return;
    }
    p = root;
    while(p != NULL)
    {
        q = p;
        if(x <= p->data)
            p = p->left;
        else
            p = p->right;
    }
    if(x <= q->data)
        q->left = newrec;
    else
        q->right = newrec;
}

void delete(node *root, int x)
{
    node *p, *q, *r;
    if(root == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nTree is Empty");
        return;
    }
    p = root;
    while(p != NULL && p->data != x)
    {
        q = p;
        if(x <= p->data)
            p = p->left;
        else
            p = p->right;
    }
    if(p == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nElement not Found");
        return;
    }
    if(p->left == NULL && p->right == NULL)     // 0 child
    {
        if(p == root)
            root = NULL;
        else if(q->left == p)
                q->left = NULL;
            else
                q->right = NULL;
        free(p);
        return;
    }
    if(p->left != NULL && p->right == NULL)     // (1 child) left child but not right child
    {
        if(p == root)
            root = p->left;
        else if(q->left == p)
                q->left = p->left;
            else
                q->right = p->left;
        p->left = NULL;
        free(p);
        return;
    }
    if(p->left == NULL && p->right != NULL)     // (1 child) right child but not left child
    {
        if(p == root)
            root = p->right;
        else if(q->left == p)
                q->left = p->right;
            else
                q->right = p->right;
        p->right = NULL;
        free(p);
        return;
    }
    // 2 child
    r = p->right;
    q = p;
    while(r->left != NULL)
    {
        q = r;
        r = r->left;
    }
    p->data = r->data;
    if(q->left == r)
        q->left = r->right;
    else
        q->right = r->right;
    r->left = NULL;
    r->right = NULL;
    free(r);
}

void inorder(node *root)
{
    if(root != NULL)
    {
        inorder(root->left);
        printf("%d ", root->data);
        inorder(root->right);
    }
}

void preorder(node *root)
{
    if(root != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ", root->data);
        preorder(root->left);
        preorder(root->right);
    }
}

void postorder(node *root)
{
    if(root != NULL)
    {
        postorder(root->left);
        postorder(root->right);
        printf("%d ", root->data);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int ch, x;
    node *root1;
    /*
    root1 = (node *) malloc(sizeof(node));
    root1->data = 1;
    root1->left = NULL;
    root1->right = NULL;
    */
    root1 = NULL;

    while(1)
    {
        printf("\nMENU");
        printf("\n1.Insert 2.Delete 3.Display 4.Exit");
        printf("\nEnter choice : ");
        scanf("%d", &ch);
        if(ch == 4)
            break;
        switch(ch)
        {
            case 1: printf("\nEnter element to Insert : ");
                    scanf("%d", &x);
                    insert(root1, x);
                    printf("\n%d ", root1->data);
                    break;
            case 2: printf("\nEnter element to delete : ");
                    scanf("%d", &x);
                    delete(root1, x);
                    break;
            case 3: if(root1 == NULL)
                        printf("\nTree is Empty");
                    else
                    {
                        printf("\nInorder   : ");
                        inorder(root1);
                        printf("\nPreorder  : ");
                        preorder(root1);
                        printf("\nPostorder :");
                        postorder(root1);
                    }
                    break;
            default: printf("\nInvalid Choice");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In the `insert` function the assignment `root = newrec` will not do anything. As soon as the function ends the life-time of `root` ends as well and all modifications to it will be lost. You need to emulate pass by reference here. Or return the new root.

Comment: Also, iterative handling of trees add a lot of complexity. Trees are better and simpler handled by using recursion.

Comment: How to pass root1 from main function by reference ? And iterative handling in case of searching you are telling ?

Comment: And if the problem is with referencing then why insertion (when root is not NULL) and deletion is working properly?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is here:

```
void insert(node *root, int x)
{
    ...
    if(root == NULL)
    {
        root = newrec;
        return;
    }
```

This operation does not do anything because `root` is a local variable.
I suggest returning a new root from `insert()`.

```
node* insert(node *root, int x)
{
    ...
    if(root == NULL)
    {
        return newrec;
    }
    ...
    return root;
}
```

Usage:

```
root1 = insert(root1, x);
```

This approach could be handy if the tree become auto-balancing because the root could change due to tree-rotations.

Comment: Yeah. I did the same thing for insert and delete function. Now it is working fine. But even when return type of delete was void and not node* code was working properly. It should not work according to me.

Answer (score 0):

In C all function arguments are passed *by value*. This means the value in the call is *copied* into the functions local argument variable.

Lets take a simple example program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(int x)
{
    x = 10;
}

int main(void)
{
    int a = 0;
    foo(a);   // Here the value of a is copied into the foo argument variable x
    printf("a = %d\n", a);
}
```

For the above program, the output will be

```
a = 0
```

With the call `foo(a)` the current value of `a` is copied into the `foo` variable `x` (as already said in the comment). The assignment `x = 10` inside the `foo` function will only modify the value of the local variable `x`. The variable `a` in the `main` function will not be modified.

So far this should not be difficult to understand I hope.

Now for pointers, it's the same thing. If you pass a pointer to a function, the value of the pointer variable is copied into the local variable inside the function. And assignment to the local variable inside the function only modifies the local variable itself.

Lets take another simple example, using strings:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(const char *x)
{
    x = "bar";
}

int main(void)
{
    const char *a = "hello";
    foo(a);
    printf("a = %s\n", a);
}
```

This will print:

```
a = hello
```

As in the first program, the value of the variable `a` is copied to the `foo` variable `x`. And the assignment to `x` will be lost when the function returns.

This is the issue you have with `root` in the `insert` and `delete` functions. When you assign to `root` you only assign to the local variable inside those functions, the original variable used in the calls will not be modified since its value was copied.

One way to solve that problem is to *emulate* pass by reference (since C doesn't have pass by reference). This is done by passing a pointer to the variable to the function.

Lets modify the second example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(const char **x)
{
    // x is a pointer to a pointer, dereference it to get the
    // original pointer
    *x = "bar";
}

int main(void)
{
    const char *a = "hello";
    foo(&a);  // Pass a pointer to the variable `a`
    printf("a = %s\n", a);
}
```

Unlike the previous program, this new will print:

```
a = bar
```

It is this technique that you need to use in your functions as well.

---

If we take the last program, where we emulate pass by reference, and draw out the pointers it will look something like this before the assignment to `x`:

```
+----------+    +-----------+    +---------+
| x in foo | -> | a in main | -> | "hello" |
+----------+    +-----------+    +---------+
```

Then after the assignment it will look like:

```
+----------+    +-----------+    +-------+
| x in foo | -> | a in main | -> | "bar" |
+----------+    +-----------+    +-------+
```

Comment: Ok. But when I make insert function to return root, then it worked properly. I kept delete function as it is. Then according to you element should have been deleted locally. But it is reflecting in the result. That thing I didn't understand.